# c++ writing file contents in a program

Tags: c++, file, resources, executable

I am trying to make  a program that stores selected file's (specifically: executable's) contents  in my program. The problem is I don't know how...

I have heard that You can do this by writing the contents in a program's separate resource file.

For example:

You have An executable and You want to store it in Your program in a way that the executable would be there when You close the C++ Program . How Do You do this?

So If anyone know how to do this (mainly the writing executable's contents in a C++ program), please let me know by answering here .

Comment: Can you please give more detailed example of what you're trying to do? also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Well, I know how to read a file, but I just don't know how to store it's contents in my C++ Program that they would "Stay there" after I close My C++ program.

Comment: Open a new file in write mode & copy contents there.

Comment: Is this question "how to make an executable installer that has the executable in a resource"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Microsoft Visual Studio, then it's quite easy:
In Add Resource dialog click Import, select "All Files (*.*)" so that it allows you to import executable file, and then just select the file you want there. When Custom Resource Type dialog pops up, type RCDATA into "Resource type" field.

If you open .rc file, you will see something like this:

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// RCDATA
//

IDR_RCDATA1          RCDATA               "myexecutable.exe"
```

and it will generate resource.h with following line:

```
#define IDR_RCDATA1                  101
```

In code you access it like this:

```
#include "resource.h"
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    HRSRC myResource = ::FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_RCDATA1), RT_RCDATA);
    HGLOBAL myResourceData = ::LoadResource(NULL, myResource);
    void* pMyExecutable = ::LockResource(myResourceData);
    return 0;
}
```

where pMyExecutable is pointer to first byte of this executable. How to retrieve size of this resource or other useful information you will find here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468902(v=vs.85).aspx

... here's an example how you would save binary resource like this on disk:

```
#include "resource.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    HRSRC myResource = ::FindResource(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_RCDATA1), RT_RCDATA);
    unsigned int myResourceSize = ::SizeofResource(NULL, myResource);
    HGLOBAL myResourceData = ::LoadResource(NULL, myResource);
    void* pMyExecutable = ::LockResource(myResourceData);

    std::ofstream f("C:\\x.exe", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    f.write((char*)pMyExecutable, myResourceSize);
    f.close();

    return 0;
}
```

When you build project with resource like that, this resource will become part of your "program" (.exe, .dll, ...).

Hope this helps you ;)

Comment: Thank You for Your answer, But how could I use it at run-time? Just specify "Resource Files/myfile.exe" or is there some special code??

Comment: @Buxme I've updated my answer. Now it shows how to use this kind of resource... enjoy ;)

Answer (score 1):

Program resources are a Microsoft specific enhancement; using them 
directly will make your code non-portable (which may or may not be a
problem).  An alternative that I've often used is to write a small
"preprocessor" which converts the resorces into C++ sources, which I
then compile.  For example, if the external file is simply text, I might
write something which converts it from:

```
first line
second line 
third line
```

to

```
char const* name[] =
{
    "first line",
    "second line ",
    "third line",
    NULL
};
```

I then compile this and link it in with the final program.